# Escaping the escape character

Tags: plain-tex, knuth

In the TeXbook, Knuth asks:

> Exercise 7.2
>
> Can you imagine why the designer of plain TeX decided not to make `\\` the control sequence for reverse slashes?

Is it something to do with the fact that control sequences formed by the escape character followed by a non-letter are control symbols and they expect a letter to follow?

Comment: It's not a technical decision :-)

Comment: `\answer` Reverse slashes (backslashes) are fairly uncommon in formulas or text, and ``\\`` is very easy to type; it was therefore felt best not to
reserve ``\\`` for such limited use. Typists can define ``\\`` to be whatever
they want (including `\backslash`).

Comment: The TeXBook has answers to all questions at the end, you are allowed to look:-)

Comment: I should note that ``\\`` ***has*** a definition when Plain TeX starts off: ``\meaning\\`` prints `macro:#1pt->#1`

Comment: @egreg Incidentally, in [*The TeX tuneup of 2008*](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb29-2/tb92knut.pdf), Knuth almost considers that definition a bug (it's `iii.` under “Here are some other things that I don't want to touch:”): _The format `plain.tex` leaves `\box0=\hbox {\tenex B}`; and it also defines ``\\`` to be a macro
such that “``\\10pt``” expands to “`10`” (for example). I could have cleaned these up by saying something like `{\setbox1=\box0} \let\\=\undefined` but I decided not to change it, since `plain.tex` is so widely used as is._

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Yes, Knuth's very conservative and doesn't change things if not really needed. I seem to remember some place where the fact ``\\`` has a definition when `plain.fmt` is loaded has an unexpected consequence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Knuth answers this in the [TeXbook code](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/knuth/dist/tex/texbook.tex) (lines 2,300-2,305, or p 307):

```
\exercise Can you imagine why the designer of plain \TeX\ decided not
to make `|\\|' the control sequence for reverse slashes?^^{backslash}
\answer Reverse slashes (backslashes) are fairly uncommon in formulas or
text, and |\\| is very easy to type; it was therefore felt best not to
reserve |\\| for such limited use. Typists can define |\\| to be whatever
they want (including |\backslash|).
```

or formatted:

> Q: Can you imagine why the designer of plain TeX decided not to make `\\` the control sequence for reverse slashes?
>
> A: Reverse slashes (backslashes) are fairly uncommon in formulas or text, and `\\` is very easy to type; it was therefore felt best not to reserve `\\` for such limited use. Typists can define `\\` to be whatever they want (including `\backslash`).